# Reformat each two-line sequence into two columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I would like to tab my printout:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

to

```
1 2 5 6
3 4 7 8
```

How to adjust it using simple command line (`awk` or `sed`)??

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to use `awk` and `paste`:

```
paste -sd'\t' <(awk 'NR%2' inputfile) <(awk '!(NR%2)' inputfile)
```

The idea is to get odd and even lines separately and `paste` those.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
1 2 5 6
3 4 7 8
```

Answer (score 6):

With `sed`:

```
sed 'N;N;N;s/\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\n\)/ \2\1 /'
```

Comment: This is the only answer here that  actually fulfills the requirements: format not just one but _each_ two-line sequence (translated, that is four lines) into two columns. The other answers fall short if number of lines is a multiple of 4 (some fail even with OPs input).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
$ cat file
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

```
$ awk 'NR%2 { even[++x] = even[x] ? even[x] FS $0 : $0 ; next }
            { odd[++y] = odd[y] ? odd[y] FS $0 : $0 }
       END  { printf "%s\n%s\n", even[x], odd[y] }' file
1 2 5 6
3 4 7 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Perl way:

```
perl -ne 's/\n/ / if $.%2!=0; print' file
```

It simply replaces the newline chartacter (`\n`) with a space on odd numbered lines. Run on your data, it produces:

```
$ perl -ne 's/\n/ / if $.%2!=0; print' file 
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in the [TXR language](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/):

Naive:

```
@(repeat)
@a @b
@c @d
@e @f
@g @h
@(output)
@a @b @e @f
@c @d @g @h
@(end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr reshape.txr -
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
1 2 5 6
3 4 7 8
A B
C D
E F
G H
A B E F
C D G H
```

Issue: it consumes data which doesn't have the right "shape".   This version falls back on consuming and printing a line if there is no match for the eight-element block shape that is being transformed.

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@a @b
@c @d
@e @f
@g @h
@    (output)
@a @b @e @f
@c @d @g @h
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

```
$ cat data
foo

a l
m o
s t
!
# $
% ^
* (
@ +

bar
$ txr reshape8.txr data
foo

a l
m o
s t
!
# $ * (
% ^ @ +

bar
```

Just in case the question actually means that consecutive pairs of lines are made adjacent, the code would be modified like this:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@a
@b
@    (output)
@a @b
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Comment: This does not seem to give the output the OP wants. The question asks for each consecutive set of two lines to be concatenated. As far as I can tell, your script only does this for certain lines. The expected output would be `foo a l\nm o s t\n`.

Comment: @terdon I don't see that anywhere. The code works for the example given.

Comment: @terdon I added a simplified version which simply joins pairs of lines into a single line. However, I don't see the requirement you're hinting at that blank lines should be deleted (that `foo`, a blank line and `a l` become `foo a l`).

Comment: No, I meant that the OP is asking for every second line to be concatenated. Look at the desired output in the OP. Nothing about ignoring blank lines. This looks fine but I don't have a `txr` interpreter installed and none seems to be available on the debian repositories so I can't check (I added a link to where you can get one).